# What is the upscaling factor in super resolution with deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I have been reading papers on single image super resolution (SISR) and I frequently encounter X3 upscaling factor, X4 upscaling factors.

Example: [SRGAN mentioning x4 upscaling factor](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.04802.pdf)

It would be wonderful if anyone could explain it in simpler words. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upscaling factor simply denotes how much the original will be upscaled. In the case of SRGAN, which uses 4x upscaling, this simply means that the output image will be four times as large as the input image. An input image of size 720 by 1080 pixels will be of size 2880 by 4320 pixels after being upscaled using SRGAN.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation!